# Setting maximum date and minimum date to CalendarView in Android C#

Tags: java, c#, calendarview

I am trying to set the minimum date of a calendarview object on an alarm application I am building in Rider to today.

I add seven days to the datetime object and then assign the milliseconds property of that object as the maximum date to the calendarview, but the calendar shows up with the year 1970 and date 1 o January enabled. The rest of the days are disabled. Why is this happening as the code am using seems to be logically correct?

```
 void Setup()
        {
            //get the current date from the system
            DateTime today= DateTime.Today;
            //get the time in millis 
            //set the calendarview minimum date to this
            mycalendar.MinDate = today.Millisecond;
            //add seven days 
            DateTime addseven =today.AddDays(7);
            //set the maximum date on the calendar
            mycalendar.MaxDate = addseven.Millisecond;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own using the Calendar class of Android Java. Just get an instance and assign the millisecond property of that instance to the minimum date and then add seven days to the instance using CalendarField.Date as type of adjustment like below

```
  void Setup()
        {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.Instance;
            mycalendar.MinDate = calendar.TimeInMillis;
            //add seven days to the time
            calendar.Add(CalendarField.Date,7);
            //assign the new time to the maximum 
            mycalendar.MaxDate = calendar.TimeInMillis;

        }
```